# rEFInd very slow to load initramfs

Tags: arch-linux, boot, initramfs, refind, plymouth

I'm trying to switch from grub to rEFInd, and I get much slower boot time. rEFInd itself it fast to load (I disabled auto detect) but when it comes to loading the kernel it hangs on "loading initramfs.... with options ... " for about 20 seconds before giving hand to plymouth boot screen.

Here is my config refind.conf :

```
timeout 5 
include themes/refind-ambience/theme.conf 
scanfor manual,external
scan_delay 0
default_selection 1
showtools reboot, shutdown, firmware
use_graphics_for windows
menuentry "Arch Linux" {
  icon /EFI/refind/themes/refind-ambience/icons/os_arch.png
  volume "MyVolumeUUID"
  loader vmlinuz-hydrolinux
  initrd initramfs-hydrolinux.img
  options "root=/dev/mapper/Milkyway-Mars rw cryptdevice=UUID=MyCryptDiskUUID:Mydisk:allow-discards quiet splash acpi_rev_override=1"
}
```

My init hooks :

```
MODULES="i915"
HOOKS="base udev plymouth autodetect keyboard keymap consolefont modconf block plymouth-encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck"
```

How could I make rEFInd faster to load initramfs ? I tried to let the  initramfs image uncompressed but it was even worst. It's now compressed with standard gzip and according to lsinitcpio it should take 0.3 seconds to decompress it. It's worth noting that grub loads that image (with the same parameters) almost instantly.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I'm now experiencing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Weird, I'm also experiencing this problem. Just like OP, rEFInd itself loads very fast, but hangs for about 30 seconds on the "loading initramfs" screen. From there, my system boots very quickly.

Comment: I unfortunately have no solution for now... I switched back to grub, less fancy but way faster.

Comment: According to the author of rEFInd, this happens when your /boot is ext2: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958989/refind-very-slow-boot-when-using-efi-stub-loader